# async vs non-async methods in a new library

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

In .NET 4.5, there are many methods that now come in async and non-async pairs, such as `Flush()` and `FlushAsync()`. Ideally I/O interactions would always be asynchronous where possible (you can always block with `.Wait()` if you really want to), but the non-async (blocking) versions obviously need to remain due to backwards compatibility.

When rolling out a completely new library that has no backwards compatibility restrictions, is there any reason why one would include the non-async methods?

Comment: I would say this is a bit opinionated (because if you just overload them by using wait in your implementation than nothing can be gained) but I would include those - no need to force your user to async if he does not want (no matter if his reasons are good or bad) - but this is just my *opinion* (node.js people will have a quite different) - this is why your question might be closed soon - there can be no good answer

Comment: I don't think it's just a matter of opinion... I'm pretty sure there is some kind of guideline or best practice somewhere. Then again a best practice is an opinion, so maybe we shouldn't ask for best practices on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Gigi maybe you should ask *this* on Meta ;) - I just wanted to give you a hint why you have 2 close flags right now - not to argue

Comment: @CarstenKönig absolutely - I appreciate it. I was aware of the risk when I posted this, given how zealous SO'ers are to close questions, but I prefer to have people contribute knowledge and have my question closed, than to have no knowledge at all.

Comment: @CarstenKönig It's true that this question might be considered "opinionated", but I think the value of the question outweighs this completely - this is exactly something people want to find when googling "async vs non-async" etc.

Answer (score 7):

Async methods usually have a cost associated with them as there is a state machine generated by the compiler which results in quite a bit of extra code. If you are not using the `async` methods they won't be jitted so you avoid that cost.

If you use the `async` version and simply call `Wait()` you are risking a [deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and also you would incur an extra context switch once the `async` operation completes. So overall the result would perform slightly worse.

Also any exceptions you get will now be wrapped in an `AggregatedException` so there will be extra work in exception processing as well. Have a look at [Async Performance: Understanding the Costs of Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx)

Comment: This is a good point, however, you should bear in mind that all those costs are almost always trivial compared to the underlying I/O request. So using asynchronous I/O is fine and dandy, pretty much any time (after all, you're doing the same when doing e.g. File.ReadAllBytes - it's just happening in a lower layer). Using it for CPU work etc. is pricier, however, there *is* a guideline against making `XXXAsync` methods just wrap a synchronous code in `Task.Run`, so if you're doing proper asynchronous work, the cost isn't that bad.

Comment: This is very interesting actually. But if the non-async method cannot simply wrap the async method, then how do you go about implementing them both without duplicating code?

Comment: @Gigi Well, it's not necessarily code duplication, but yeah, you will not "reuse" the code. If you simply did a `Wait` on the async method (or `Task.Run` on the sync method, god forbid :D), there's no point in having the method there. Have a look at the .NET reference source code, you can see how it works with e.g. `FileStream` (which has some complicated async/sync methods) or `Socket` (which is pretty straight-forward).

Answer (score 4):

Ned's answer is pretty good, so I will not repeat what he said (although do note that the overhead isn't necessarily large compared to the cost of the I/O operation itself).

One more significant reason to provide the synchronous methods is actually obvious in hindsight - people have serious trouble understanding asynchronous operations. They're used to doing "Read, then write, then read again..." Error handling, error locality, synchronization... all can get very tricky very easily, especially if you can't use `await`.

The truth is, while it would be very nice if everything became asynchronous over time, it's much harder to reason about asynchronous applications. It's still better than doing multi-threading, but not by a whole lot.

In this way, using asynchronous methods can be seen as an optimization - and you don't do optimizations unless you *know* they're going to help significantly. For a library, this is tough to decide - so provide both options. Someone writing a high-throughput server will take the care needed to write a performant and reliable asynchronous application. Someone just writing a simple CMS, for example, might want to avoid it entirely.

This applies especially for C#/.NET below 4.5 - try doing error handling on asynchronous continuations without `await`, and you'll see what I'm talking about :)

Keeping code simple is very important. It lowers development and maintenance costs considerably, and makes it easier to understand for newcomers.

Answer (score 4):

There are slight differences (mostly negligible) between `async` and synchronous versions but I would say that **there's no reason anymore to have both versions** of the same operation. You should decide during the implementation of your library which version fits best. A naturally asynchronous operation (e.g. downloading a file) should be `async` and CPU bound operations should be synchronous.

You can see that paradigm being used in the WinRT framework:

> To achieve those goals, we made many potentially I/O-bound APIs asynchronous in the Windows Runtime. These are the most likely candidates to visibly degrade performance if written synchronously (e.g. could likely take longer than 50 milliseconds to execute). This asynchronous approach to APIs sets you up to write code that is fast and fluid by default and promotes the importance of app responsiveness in Metro style app development.

From [Keeping apps fast and fluid with asynchrony in the Windows Runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/03/20/keeping-apps-fast-and-fluid-with-asynchrony-in-the-windows-runtime.aspx)

It used to be the case that using the asynchronous overloads was immensely harder and more complicated than the synchronous ones so having both versions was a good idea. **With `async-await` that is no longer the case.**

Answer (score 0):

The only reason is if you want support applications that targets a .NET Framework prior 4.5. If you have such applications and you want to use your new library then you are forced to use the non async way.

You can compile your new assembly also with .NET 4.0 by using the [Async Targeting Package.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/). Doing that I suggest you to create two projects: one with 4.5 and one with 4.0.

Comment: Actually, 4.0 is fine as well even without ATP, you just can't use `await`. Which of course means it's very tricky to get things right, but I've been forced to do just that many times already, and it does work. And of course, if you've got `await` in your library, your consumers will have to be 4/4.5 as well, so doing the non-async versions will not help anyway.